# Maven plug-in dependency

Tags: maven

I'm getting the error: The parameters 'file', 'url' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file are missing or invalid.  I had it working before for a snapshot and cannot figure out what is wrong. Any clues?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>deploy-zip-dll</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy-file</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <repositoryId>releases</repositoryId>
                     <url>https://ess.modusoperandi.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
                 <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                 <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                 <version>${project.version}</version>
                 <file>/target/MATLAB_JNI_DLL-bin.zip</file>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: up the stacktrace ..

Comment: How are you executing Maven? With `mvn deploy:deploy-file`?

Comment: Using a POM file through eclipse right now, but will eventually run on Jenkins.

Comment: your file looks like an absolute path. Could you try <file>${basedir}/target/... instead?

Comment: Still get t he same error.

Comment: I was deploy:deploy-file.  I just needed to run the phase deploy and it saw the parameters.